# How to fetch the page id and use it for an image name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in php. I want to make a condition for showing page id and set my image name is pageId and show this background image in my header banner. How to fetch page id use it fetching image for my banner background img.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="splash">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/<?php echo $page;?>.jpg" />
</div>
```

and it is also working in loop in different page change header banner image if change page.

I have a problem in this code. It is working fine for pages but if i go inner pages or post of a page it shows banner i want to hide that. how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

You're close...Assuming you're on a single post/page template, you can use [get_the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID):

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/' . get_the_ID() . '.jpg'; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID() ?>
<div class="splash">
                  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/<?php echo  $postid;?>.jpg" />
                </div>
```

Comment: Answer working fine but if i goes inside any category it is not working can you give a tip how to do in that conditions.

Comment: inside category means?

Answer (score 0):

**Page id and Page banner**

- You can have a MySQL (or any RDBMS) table 'page' with columns [id, title, body, image_path]
- I have just tried to assume basic fields for 'page' table - you may extend it further according to your requirements.

**Required functions**

- Once table is ready you may write functions
- getBannerByPageId(id) - this function will return whole `image path` along with the image name.
- getPageId() - this function will return the `id` of currently displayed page. Here id can be fetched from the URL. In case you are using clean urls then you will need extend your functionality to map the `page id` and `url alias`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?> //to get page id
```

Reference [get page id](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

```
<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?> //to get directory uri..
```

Reference [get directory uri](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

**And combine those by**

```
<div class="splash">

<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/<?php echo $postid; ?>.jpg" />
```